# Angular 10+ converting base64 image to form data

Tags: angular, base64, multipart

Is there a way for an interceptor to convert a base64 image to multipart/form-data?
I have an external component that converts uploads to base64 and the sends it to a local API. Latest requirements state that I should send it as a multipart/form-data. Giving the fact that I cannot request that from that external component, can I achieve that locally with angular interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

using pipe() will do the work.

see this article:

https://indepth.dev/posts/1051/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You might be lucky if the external component is an Angular library style component, and uses Angular's `HttpClient` API. If that's the case, then I believe that the `HttpInterceptor` interface will allow you to access the component's requests.

Otherwise, if the external component is using `XMLHttpRequest` you could intercept its calls by overriding the `XMLHttpRequest.open` method like this :

[Override XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778218/2025271)